# Regexp matching for some text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text:

```
@title1

Some stuff here and some @junk@ here

@newheader

Multiple lines. 
Multiple lines. 
Multiple lines. 

@title3

Extra stuff here.
```

I need a regexp that would match the text after the titles. First match should return

> Some stuff here and some @junk@ here

Also, title is something that starts on a new line with @ and it's followed by some non space characters

http://jsfiddle.net/QCNfQ/2/

Comment: What regular expressions have you tried already? Why didn't they work?

Comment: Can't figure out how to say, match everything until next group (which would be a title). Tried something like: `/(\n?@\w+\n)([\S\s]*)(?!(\n?@\w+\n))/g` , but the last part is ignored, it returns everything after the title.

Comment: Need more info on the formatting rules that apply to the text. For example, if titles always start with @title, but otherlines never do, you can use that, but we don't have enough info to assume

Comment: Edited question to reflect this...No, basically title can be any word, it's delimited only by @ and new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/u5Khe/

You're looking for this RE: `/(?:^|\n)@([^@\n]+)\s*((?:[\S\s](?!\n@))+)/g`.

Code:

```
var string = "@title1\n\nTest @case@ one\n\n@title2\n\nMulti" +
             "\nline\nstring\n\n@title3\n\nfinal test";
var results = [];

var re = /(?:^|\n)@([^@\n]+)\s*((?:[\S\s](?!\n@))+)/g;
var matches = null;
while((matches = re.exec(string)) != null){
    /* matches[0] = whole block
       matches[1] = title
       matches[2] = body
     */
     var body = matches[2].replace(/\^s+|\s$/g,"");
     results.push(body);
}
//results.length will be 3;
alert(results.join("\n-----------------------\n"));
//Shows an alert with all matches, separated by "\n----------------\n"
```

Explanation of RE:

- `(?:^|\n)@` seeks for the beginning of the title (`^@` = "@ at the beginning of a text", `\n@` = "@ at the beginning of a new line"
- `([^@\n]+)` means: Match every character except for @ or newline (delimiter of title, as defined by OP)
- `((?:[\S\s](?!\n@))+)` means: Select all `+` characters `\S\s`, which are not followed by a newline + @ `(?!\n@)`.
- `/g` is the "global" flag = "attempts to get as much matches as possible on a given string"

Your string should be formatted like this:

```
@title
Body

@title2
Anything, from @ to @, as long as the next line doesn't start with a @
 @ (There's a whitespace before this @)

@custom title@ Delimited by the @

@Foo
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this:

`/(@title\d)(\s)*(.*)/gi;`

and then access the third (`$3`) group.

So...

```
var a = "@title1\n\nSome stuff here and some @junk@";
var a1 = "@title2\n\nExtra stuff here.";

var b = /(@title\d)(\s)*(.*)/gi;
var c = a.replace(b, '$3');
var d = a1.replace(b, '$3');

document.write(c + '<br />' + d);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/5Chjf/

fyi... this assumes that `@title` starts every other line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var text = "@title1

Some stuff here and some @junk@

@title2

Extra stuff here."; 

var output = text.replace(/([^@]+@)(\w+@)/,
            function (all, g1, g2) {
                return [g2, g1].join('');
            }
    );

alert(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'\n@title1   test'.match(/(?:\n@title\d)(?:[\s|\n])*(.*)/)[1]
```